# How to add a new Label to the window when a button is pressed in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a program that when you click the button it displays what's inside the textbox in the window as a new label

so far this is what the code looks like

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="firstwpfapp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:firstwpfapp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Margin="-120,-142,0,0" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="451*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Wrapper">

    </StackPanel>

    <TextBox x:Name="input" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="106,198,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter here" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166"/>
    <Button  Content="Button" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166" Height="26" Click="addTask"/>

</Grid>
```

C#

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace firstwpfapp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void addTask(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {





            String val = input.GetLineText().ToString();
            Label todo = new Label();
            todo.Content = val;
            Wrapper.Children.Add(todo);



        }
    }
}
```

So far nothing get's added to the window when I press the button.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do?

`String val = input.GetLineText().ToString
Label todo = new Label(); 
todo.Location = new Point(15, 15); //or whatever location you want to put your label
todo.Text = val; 
this.Controls.Add(todo);`

Comment: yes but it throws error "MainWindow" does not contain controls

Comment: Ah sorry.  Use your original Wrapper.Children.Add(todo) instead of my last line.

Comment: I did that but it's not showing up when button is clicked

Comment: Bummer. Last question - is there a reason you can't go ahead and create the label in Xaml where you want it, give it an x:Name and then set it's default value as Hidden? Then when your button is clicked you can make it visible at that time?

Comment: I don't wanna do that because I am making a todo list program and I want to add custom label everytime.

Comment: Now I have a problem everytime I click the button it stacks instead of droping like a list

Comment: You may want to create a new question since this is not related to this question of how to programmatically create a new label - but once you do please post the link.

Comment: ok here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54848269/how-to-stop-label-from-stacking-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Does this compile? According to the documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.getlinetext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_TextBox_GetLineText_System_Int32_) the method `GetLineText()` requires an integer parameter to be passed in.  If you want the whole text value you could use the `.Text` property.

In addition you haven’t defined a size/position for your StackPanel and it may not be visible.

Also `GetLineText(int)` already returns a string, there’s no need to call `.ToString()`

Comment: You are right I meant to do input.ToString(); Either way, it doesn't achieve my goal

Comment: I believe you want `input.Text` to get the contents of the TextBox.

Comment: yea that worked. But it's not placing the input value on the window when the button is clicked

Comment: As you haven’t defined any location/size for your StackPanel, I’m not exactly sure where it will be located and it may not be visible.

Comment: I found the solution by adding a new grid on the window adding it there. Thank you so much for helping me :)