# How to stop Label from stacking in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating a program where if you click the button it adds a new label. However the problem is that when you click the add button the label keeps getting stack on top of eachother instead of being a list

Here is the code

c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace firstwpfapp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void addTask(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String val = input.ToString();
            Label todo = new Label();
            todo.Content = val;
            List.Children.Add(todo);
        }
    }
}
```

xaml

```
...
<Window x:Class="firstwpfapp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:firstwpfapp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Margin="-120,-142,0,0" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="451*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Wrapper"Background="LightGray" Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="input" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="106,198,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter here" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166"/>
        <Button  Content="Button" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166" Height="26" Click="addTask"/>
        <Grid x:Name="List" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="391" Margin="507,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="385"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the list keeps getting stack on top of another each time the button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the Grid

```
<Grid x:Name="List" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="391" Margin="507,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="385"/>
```

with a StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="List" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="391" Margin="507,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="385"/>
```

Adding child elements to a grid stacks them on top of each other (as you have noticed)
A StackPanel adds new child elements below (or after) the previous child element.

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead and add your items to a `ListView` which will stack the items for you as well as include an `ItemSource` that we can bind to so it will create the rows for each new ToDo item for you:

Note: I have not tested the below; I'm on my Macbook.

1. Instead of your `Wrapper` StackLayout, replace it with:

`<ListView Name="Wrapper" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" />`

2. Now, create a new file called `Task.cs` which we will use when creating a new type of Task (add the below to the Task.cs file):

   `public class Task { public string task { get; set;} }`
3. Have your MainWindow inherit from the INotifyPropertyChanged interface [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged)

   `public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged`
4. Now update the rest of your code behind of `MainWindow` to:

   ```
   private ObservableCollection<Task> _tasks;
   //Tasks will store all of the tasks of type Task that we add to it 
   //as well as be bound to our ListView that will display whatever we add to our Tasks
   public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks
   {
       get
       {
           return _tasks;
       }

       set
       {
           if (value != _tasks)
           {
               _tasks = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("Tasks");
           }
       }
   }
   //Here we implement OnPropertyChanged so our ObservableCollection can be notified 
   //whenever we have a new task added to or removed from Tasks (this is created when we implement INotifyPropertyChanged
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
       {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
       }
   }
   //Create a new Task and add it to our Tasks any time the addTask button is clicked
   private void addTask(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

       Tasks.Add(new Task(input.Text));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...................

XAML:

```
 <Grid> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Margin="0,50,0,0">
        <TextBox Name="Input"
                 Width="300"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Button Name="AddBtn"
                Content="Add"
                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Width="100" 
                Click="AddBtn_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListView Name="ItemListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LabelItems, Mode=OneWay}"
              Grid.Row="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Margin="20"/>
</Grid>
```

C# code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _labels = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> LabelItems
    {
        get { return _labels; }
        set { _labels = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Input.Text != "" && Input.Text != null)
        {
            LabelItems.Add(Input.Text);
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```